# converting a perl split regex to C#

Tags: perl, c#-4.0, windows-7

I have an old perl regex defined like this

```
my @data = split(/^[0-9]{1,3}\)?\t/m, $CLIP->GetText());
```

C# doesn't like the regex and says Unrecognized escape sequence? How can i fix this?

I tried this in C#

```
Regex rex = new Regex("/^[0-9]{1,3}\)?\t/m");
```

Comment: Did you type that in literally... you need to use C# constructs... strings, `Regex` etc.

Comment: yeah my friend told me it would work... I know little of perl, c# and regex's so i came here for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `\)`. The easiest way to fix the problem is by changing the string to a verbatim string like this:

```
Regex rex = new Regex(@"^[0-9]{1,3}\)?\t");
```

Also, you don't need the slashes and the trailing m in this case.

Comment: Aren't the starting and ending slashes (and `m`) not actually part of the regular expression? It looks to me like how it is in javascript.

Comment: @cowboydan The question is tagged with C# 4, so that should not be a problem. However, since this is not essential to the issue, I have removed the use of `var`.